# Need to know a fast and efficient way to compare two very large arrays in MuleSoft

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am fetching all records from a MySQL table ( customTable) , this table has a primary key. I am also querying all records from salesforce objects (customTable__c) from salesforce.
I am trying to find the records which are in salesforce but have been deleted from the database.
Both table and salesforce have around 80k records. I am using the below script for the comparison but this script is taking a very long time to finish.

salesforce data is coming in JSON format :

```
[
        {
            "Product_Line__c": "Sample",
            "ExternalId__c": "a9M5C000000GoJxUAK",
        },
        {
            "Product_Line__c": "Sample2",
            "ExternalId__c": "a9M5C000000GoJxUAL"
        }
]
```

database records are coming in JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "changed_on": "2021-12-08T11:24:50",
    "primaryKey":"a9M5C000000GoJxUAL"
  },
  {
   
    "changed_on": "2021-12-08T11:24:50",
     "primaryKey":"a9M5C000000GoJxUAQ"
  }
]
```

The primary key is a character string

expected output  ( difference of primary/external id in salesforce and database:

```
[
   "ExternalId__c" : "a9M5C000000GoJxUAK",
   "Is_RM_Deleted__c" : true
]
```

Do we have any other good way there we can get below operation very faster?

salesforce.externaID is an array of 80k records

database.primaryKey is an array of 80k records

```
 %dw 2.0
   output application/json
    (salesforce.externalID -- database.primaryKey) 
     map {
    
        "ExternalId__c": $,
        "Is_RM_Deleted__c": true
    }
```

Comment: Please show a snippet with examples of records in each array so we can understand the structure of each record. What are the formats for each input? Is the DataWeave script complete? It doesn't define a header nor an output type. What is the actual output type?

Comment: Updated my question as per your comment, test dataweave script is complete. Forgot to mentioned the output type as json

Answer (score 1):

Usually, DW is not the bottleneck when it comes to performance.
You are loading 160k records from the DB and Salesforce.
By default Mulesoft will try to stream those and will only load a couple of records at first.
In your DW code you are consuming both streams which means that it is at the time of executing your DW transformation that Mulesoft loads all 160K records in memory and this can take some time.

If you want find how much time does it take to consume each stream,
you can add a transform operators with sizeOf() after your DB and Salesforce queries. This sizeOf() functions consumes the stream and this is how you can time it.

If the performance bottleneck is loading the data, you may have to break it down into smaller chunks.

If you already have the data in memory, you can try something like that:

If loading the records in memory is not the bottleneck, you can try something like that:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var salesforce = [
    { externalID: 1 }, 
    { externalID: 2 },
    { externalID: 3 }
]

var database = [
    { primaryKey: 1 },
    { primaryKey: 2 }
]

var bSearch = java!java::util::Arrays::binarySearch

var databaseSortedArray = database.primaryKey orderBy ($)
---
salesforce 
    filter ((databaseSortedArray bSearch $.externalID) < 0)
    map {
        ExternalId__c: $.externalID,
        Is_RM_Deleted__c: true,
    }
```

This uses the standard java function for binary search which requires the PrimaryKey array to be sorted.
For better performance you can add order by clause to the SQL query so that the sorting will be done in the DB.

Comment: If we assume the output will be used for other processing inside the application the output should be application/java, to avoid extra processing time formatting to JSON, then more time parsing it. If the output is going directly to the client of a REST API then it is fine to output JSON directly.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.

Comment: Thanks, @MrM for the detailed explanation with an alternative approach. Let me try the solution you shared.
I am thinking we can somehow use dataweave dreaming in any way ( not possible I believe as dataweave is loading everything into the memory for the comparison ) , so this cant be done in anyways with streaming.

Comment: Also, I am trying to create a salesforce bulk insert job after this transformation.

Comment: Then use output application/Java.

Comment: Hi @aled I tried to replicate the same thing with binary search ( keeping data as integer and already sorted ) it took me more time as compared to -- operator.

Comment: I checked the time mule is taking to load 40k records into memory by using sizeOf function and ti was around 500ms. Though the same amount of records is taking 6 minutes to get the difference using the mentioned dataweave script.

Comment: What is the difference in performance between using application/json output vs. application/dw if I'm passing the result to another event processor?