# Need to sync database to salesforce where database refreshing everyday

Tags: mule, esb, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a table in the MySQL database having 80k records. These records are refreshed every day with some ETL tools. So many new records are inserted, updated, or may be deleted.
I am interested to sync only deleted records to salesforce.

I don't have an efficient way to know which data has been deleted in the database so that I can delete the same records in salesforce.

Right now, I am querying everything from the MySQL database and salesforce object and comparing unique ids to get the difference, this approach is taking away too long to find the difference.

Do we have any other faster way to sync my database table to salesforce? Please let me know if more information is needed. For payload and other details please refer to the below question.

[Please go through this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925208/need-to-know-a-fast-and-efficient-way-to-compare-two-very-large-arrays-in-muleso)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to know a fast and efficient way to compare two very large arrays in MuleSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925208/need-to-know-a-fast-and-efficient-way-to-compare-two-very-large-arrays-in-muleso)

Comment: Hi @aled, first of all, thanks for your prompt responses, another question was regarding dataweave transformation that is taking time and it is still taking the same time, right now I am doing parallel for each by breaking salesforce data into arrays of 10000 records for comparison. Here, in this question, I am trying to find out if we have any other approach to sync the database to salesforce where the database is refreshing every day.